# Дорожная сеть (графы) в БД

Tags: база-данных, графы

Каким образом в БД (MySQL) лучше хранить графы, которые описывают дороги?
Решил рисовать дороги с помощью квадратичных кривых Безье, поэтому координаты кривой определяются тремя вершинами. Также каждая группа кривых должна образовать дорогу с определенными свойствами: ориентация движения(одностороннее или не одностороннее), поверхность, состояние и другое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Таблица со списком узлов (положения)
- Таблица со списком связей (ид узлов, свойства)
- Опционально таблицы с типами и свойствами дорог (ширина, отступ от осевой, число полос, поверхность и т.п.)
- Дороги односторонние (то есть для 2-ух сторонней делается пара связей, типа 1-2 и 2-1)

Связи могут содержать веса для интерполяции пары свойств (например, переход одного типа дороги в другой)
Перекрестки так же могут быть отмечены, могут иметь приоритеты дорог, светофоры и т.п.

Пример из игры которую я декодировал в 2007:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо, жду)))

Comment: @Ni55aN обновил ответ

Comment: сделал наброски, получилось - первая таблица(вершины): идентификатор и широта/долгота, =все эти поля индексированы=. Вторая таблица(ребра): идентификатор, индексы на первую и вторую вершину, индекс на  запись с информацией о дороге =первое поле индексировано=. Третья таблица(информация о дороге): идентификатор, тип дороги, направление, покрытие и т.д.

Будут какие-то замечания по этому поводу?

Comment: @Ni55aN тут уже больше от вашей задачи зависит. У меня это дороги для игры были.

Comment: поиск кратчайшего пути использовали?

Comment: Нет, он тут относительно прост, если в вершинах хранить ссылки на связи их использующие. А* и вперед!

Answer (score 0):

SQL не оптимизирован для хранения графов. Возможно, Вам стоит попробовать Neo4J.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209607/is-storing-graphs-in-mysql-a-good-idea

Comment: @Ni55aN кто-то запрещает установить Neo4j / OrientDB?

Comment: @Etki, куда? На хостинг? В том то и дело

Comment: @Ni55aN вам, возможно, стоит почитать про VPS.

Comment: @Etki, вам, возможно, стоит обдумать даваемые советы. (если даже не знаете причин того, почему я не взял VPS)

Comment: @Ni55aN я не того что не знаю, я не понимаю причин не брать VPS, если задача сама того требует (особенно учитывая, что на серваке можно просто развернуть БД и подключаться к ней с любого хостинга).

Comment: причины - 100% ресурс поначалу не будет приносить доход, нет желания делать это в убыток

Comment: @Ni55aN дешевый впс стоит как дешевый хостинг, ну ей-богу, 200 в месяц.

Comment: 200*12, к примеру

Answer (score 0):

Помоему стоит посмотреть в сторону иерархических бд, ну а если в руках только MySQL первое что приходит в голову создание как минимум 2 таблиц:
Узлы,
cвязи